# Haskell - Recursión en listas

Tags: haskell

quisiera solicitarles ayuda con un ejercicio en Haskell.

```
type Nombre = String
type Edad = Int
type Sueldo = Float
type Empleado = (Nombre, Edad, Sueldo)

nombre :: Empleado -> Nombre
nombre (n,_,_) = n

edad :: Empleado -> Edad
edad (_,e,_) = e

sueldo :: Empleado -> Sueldo
sueldo (_,_,s) = s

empleados :: [Empleado]

empleados = [("aaa", 82, 1000), ("bbb",50,1100), ("cc",65,1150)]
```

**PARTE 1: OK** - *Devuelve empleados mayores a 60 años.*

```
proximosAJubilarse :: [Empleado] -> [Nombre]
proximosAJubilarse = (map nombre).(filter (\(_,e,_) -> e > 60))
```

**PARTE 2: OK** - *Devuelve el sueldo máximo entre todos los empleados.*

```
sueldoMaximo :: [Empleado] -> Float
sueldoMaximo = maximum.(map sueldo)
```

**PARTE 3: = No se como continuar**

*Escribir una función empleadoConSueldoMaximo :: [Empleado] −> Empleado que, dada una lista de empleados, devuelve un empleado con sueldo máximo entre todos los empleados. Se debe utilizar la función `find :: (a −> Bool) −> [a] −> Maybe a` que, dado un predicado f y una lista, devuelve algún valor de la lista que cumpla con el predicado, o devuelve Nothing en caso que no haya ninguno.*

```
find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
find f = foldr g Nothing
  where g x rc | f x = Just x
               | otherwise = rc
```

**"Inicio de solución"**

```
empleadoConSueldoMaximo :: [Empleado] -> Empleado
?
```

Comment: Este es un ejercicio de instituto? Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 2):

Antes de entrar en la respuesta, en la **Parte 1** se podría hacer quitar la función lambda y algunos paréntesis supérfluos:

```hs
proximosAJubilarse :: [Empleado] -> [Nombre]
proximosAJubilarse = map nombre . filter ((>60) . edad)
```

También en **Parte 2** sobran paréntesis:

```hs
sueldoMaximo :: [Empleado] -> Float
sueldoMaximo = maximum . map sueldo
```

Es importante señalar que esta función fallará cuando la lista de empleados esté vacía.

Veamos la **Parte 3**: usamos la función `sueldoMaximo` en la función `find`:

```hs
empleadoConSueldoMaximo xs = find ((==s).sueldo) xs
  where s = sueldoMaximo xs
```

El resultado obtenido es de tipo `Maybe Empleado`. Como queremos que sea `Empleado`, podemos extraer el dato con las funciones `fromJust` o `fromMaybe` del módulo `Data.Maybe`. Por no añadir nada más, se podría hacer algo así:

```hs
empleadoConSueldoMaximo :: [Empleado] -> Empleado
empleadoConSueldoMaximo xs = empleado
  where s = sueldoMaximo xs
        Just empleado = find ((==s).sueldo) xs
```